# R - Subscript out of bounds for reading an html link

Tags: r, web-scraping

long time - first time, so sorry for any mistakes in formatting of my question.

I am working on a web scraping function for the american football site Pro Football Reference, ([www.pro-football-reference.com](http://www.pro-football-reference.com)), and am having an error that I cannot find the origin of or reasoning behind.

Here is the start of my web scraping function in R:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(XML)

pull_AdvDefense <- function(seasons=2020){
  try(if(min(seasons) < 2018) stop('No advanced data available for seasons before 2018', call. = F))
  data_name <- data.table::data.table()
  for (x in seasons){
    adv <- (xml2::read_html(url(paste0("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/",x,"/defense_advanced.htm"))) %>% #read and interpret html table
              rvest::html_table(fill = T))[[1]]
```

and it then continues with some data cleaning and managing.

The issue is coming in the reading of the html with the error message:

```
Error in (xml2::read_html(url(paste0("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/",  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I'm not sure how it is possible for the link to be "out of bounds". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the site has some protections up against scraping. There may not be a way to get this data with rvest.